# foreign key not created with laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add a foreign key into the users tables :

a user has a town (ville in french) and a town can have many users :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('adresse');

        //un user à une seule ville
        //une ville peut avoir plusieurs users
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('villes');

        $table->foreign('villes_id')->references('id')->on('villes');
        ...


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

my villes (town) migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('villes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nom',100);
        $table->integer('cp');
        $table->string('pays',50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I renamed the migrations (I don't know if it's good to do that ?) and this is order of my migrations, like you can see, I creat villes before users :

[image]

I've got this error in the terminal :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column
>   'villes_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `users` add
>   constraint `users_villes_id_foreign` foreign key (`villes_id`)
>   references `villes` (`id`))

Comment: You're referencing `villes_id` on the `users` table but you've named your column `villes`

Comment: Great, thank you.  Sorry, I'm a Laravel beginner.

Comment: @billyonecan please answer to this message, I will validate it.  You resolve this issue before other.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your setting your foreign key on a column that doesn't exist.
The column name is `villes` but your setting foreign key on `villes_id`.

Change the column name like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('adresse');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('villes_id');
    $table->foreign('villes_id')->references('id')->on('villes');
    // ...

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, hope that you'll understand that I cannot validate your reply even it is good.  @billyonecan gave the reply first.  Thank you again Robert.

Comment: @beegees, No problem just wanted to help! I didn't even notice it was answered in comments.

Comment: You helped, thank you.  Without reaction of Billy, I validate your reply ;)